# Kullback–Leibler divergence with elements that are $0$

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

I have a problem that I need to calculate [Kullback–Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), but the problem is that I have some elements that are $0$. Is there a way that I'm able to deal with situations like that? I know that Wiki is saying that if $P(i)=0$, then $Q(i)$ has to be $0$ as well, but maybe there is an accepted workaround to get rid of the situation.

For example, I have two arrays $[1,2,3,0,6,7,0]$ and $[0,2,3,5,0,0,9]$.

Comment: How about [additive smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing)?

Comment: Accurately estimating KL-divergence is a pretty difficult problem, especially with small sample size. @ziyuang's suggestion is equivalent to putting Dirichlet prior, and is good for estimating the distribution, but it doesn't necessarily give a good estimator for KL-divergence. It will likely bias it towards zero.